# Are pyc files independent of the minor version of python?

Tags: python, version, pyc

Is it possible and safe to load pyc files made with a different minor version of python?
For instance 2.5.1 with 2.5.5?

My guess is that the magic number does not change with minor versions.
If I refer to this file [import.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/import.c?view=markup)
the magic number corresponds to the variable `pyc_magic` ( equals MAGIC or MAGIC+1 )

The file comments say:

> Magic word to reject .pyc files generated by other Python versions.
>      It should change for each incompatible change to the bytecode.

I don't see different number for python minor versions, but can we assume it won't change in the future?

Answer (score 1):

You can't assume that it won't change. Whenever I've needed to distribute .pyc files instead of readable .py files, I've ended up shipping a Python binary too.